# Stim's dem.diagram (detector error model diagram) not working for me?

Tags: stim

I've copied these lines from Stim's [Getting Started](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/getting_started.ipynb) notebook:

```
circuit = stim.Circuit.generated(
    "repetition_code:memory",
    rounds=30,
    distance=9,
    before_round_data_depolarization=0.03,
    before_measure_flip_probability=0.01)
dem = circuit.detector_error_model()
dem.diagram("matchgraph-svg")
```

but when I run it the final line gives an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[99], line 8
      1 circuit = stim.Circuit.generated(
      2     "repetition_code:memory",
      3     rounds=30,
      4     distance=9,
      5     before_round_data_depolarization=0.03,
      6     before_measure_flip_probability=0.01)
      7 dem = circuit.detector_error_model()
----> 8 dem.diagram("matchgraph-svg")

TypeError: diagram(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: stim._stim_avx2.DetectorErrorModel, *, type: str) -> stim._stim_avx2._DiagramHelper

Invoked with: stim.DetectorErrorModel('''
    error(0.02) D0
    error(0.02) D0 D1
    error(0.01) D0 D8
    error(0.02) D1 D2
    error(0.01) D1 D9
    error(0.02) D2 D3
    error(0.01) D2 D10
    error(0.02) D3 D4
    error(0.01) D3 D11
...
    detector(9, 1) D20
    detector(11, 1) D21
    detector(13, 1) D22
    detector(15, 1) D23
'''), 'matchgraph-svg'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print(stim.__version__)` and confirm you're on v1.11 or later.  Probably you're on v1.10; the getting started notebook was bumped to v1.11 last week and one of the changes was the removal of `type=` as a required keyword argument for diagram methods.

The `pip install` line in the notebook does include the minimum version.